# Populate label or attribute of form element in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I'm still fairly new to ZF3 so forgive me if I'm asking an obvious question here, but after many searches, looks through the source and head scratching, I can't seem to find an obvious approach to populating label text with data from the entity.

Basically, I have a form collection containing form elements which are each stored with a type (ID), e.g. "Business phone", "Mobile phone", etc.

Is there a way to populate anything other than a value in a form element?

Edit (more info)

So, there is a `PersonForm`, with a `Person` Fieldset which contains a `Phone` Fieldset collection:

```
$phoneFieldset = new PhoneFieldset($objectManager);

$this->add([
    "type" => Element\Collection::class,
    "name" => "Phones",
    "options" => [
        "count" => 0,
        "should_create_template" => true,
        "allow_add" => true,
        "allow_remove" => true,
        "target_element" => $phoneFieldset
    ],
]);
```

This `Phone` fieldset contains the following elements:

```
$this->add([
    "name" => "Type_ID",
    "type" => "hidden",
]);

$this->add([
    "name" => "Number",
    "type" => "text",
    "attributes" => [
        "placeholder" => "Enter phone number",
    ],
    "options" => [
        "label" => "Email" // Ideally this would be $entity->getTypeName() for example, which would return the name based on the Type_ID mapped against a constant
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, adding label information for a `formCollection` (`Fieldset` or `Collection` elements) is pretty much the same as for input elements (`Element`) ([Element docs](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/element/element/)).

Some examples:

Add a `Fieldset` into a `Form` (`$this->formCollection($form->get('address'))`):
Docs: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/element/collection/

```
$this->add(
    [
        'type'     => AddressFieldset::class, // Note: FQCN -> provided by FormElementManager
        'name'     => 'address',
        'required' => true,
        'options'  => [
            'use_as_base_fieldset' => false,
            'label'                => _('Address'),
            'label_options'        => [
                // .. add options for the label, see LabelInterface
            ],
            'label_attributes'        => [
                // .. add attributes for the label, see LabelInterface
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Renders as:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Address</legend>
    <!-- the inputs / labels of `Element` objects -->
</fieldset>
```

Add a `Collection` into a `Form` (`$this->formCollection($form->get('cities'))`):
Docs: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/element/collection/

```
$this->add(
    [
        'name'       => 'cities',
        'type'       => Collection::class,
        'options'    => [
            'label'                  => _('Cities'),
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'allow_add'              => true,
            'allow_remove'           => true,
            'count'                  => 1,
            'target_element'         => $this->getCityFieldset(), // Must be an instantiated Fieldset (so provide via Factory)
            'label_options'        => [
                // .. add options for the label, see LabelInterface
            ],
            'label_attributes'        => [
                // .. add attributes for the label, see LabelInterface
            ],
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'class'              => 'fieldset-collection',
            'data-fieldset-name' => _('City'),
        ],
    ]
);
```

Renders as:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-collection" data-fieldset-name="City">
    <legend>Cities</legend>
    <fieldset><!-- add a <legend> using JS here, with the data-fieldset-name of the parent -->
        <!-- the inputs / labels of `Element` objects -->
    </fieldset>
    <span data-template="<!-- contains entire template so you can use JS to create 'add' and 'remove' buttons for additional CityFieldset <fieldset> elements -->"></span>
</fieldset>
```

I added in the `<!-- comments -->` in the HTML output, you can figure those out ;-)

---

Additionally, if you're using an ORM, Doctrine in this example, then you could do it like this:

```
$this->add(
    [
        'name'       => 'roles',
        'required'   => true,
        'type'       => ObjectMultiCheckbox::class,
        'options'    => [
            'object_manager'     => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'       => Role::class,
            'property'           => 'id',
            'label'              => _('Roles'),
            'label_generator'    => function ($targetEntity) {
                /** @var Role $targetEntity */
                return $targetEntity->getName();
            },
            'label_options'      => [
                'label_position' => FormRow::LABEL_APPEND,
            ],
            'use_hidden_element' => true,
            'checked_value'      => 1,
            'unchecked_value'    => 0,
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'class'                => 'form-check-input',
        ],
    ]
);
```

[Doctrine Form Elements docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md)

Comment: Thanks for that. I am indeed using Doctrine, however I'm missing something obvious from the above... Perhaps I haven't registed something for the object manager to work correctly? I should further clarify my structure too. It's `Form => ParentFieldset => CollectionFieldset` - It's the collection fieldset's Element I'm trying to properly define a label from the data for.

Comment: Sure, that's the same as the 2nd (`Collection`) example. Bear in mind that child-fieldset (due to the nature of a Collection) gets **_handled_** the same way as a fieldset, just in a loop (for your set `count`), and cloned for initial ones generated. However, you **instantiate** the Fieldset _in the Factory_ (you must pass it to your Fieldset containing the Collection), as such, you'll have to set these options there (or modify the instantiated Fieldset in the Fieldset with the Collection). (E.g. in Factory: `return (new $requestedName())->setAttribute('class', 'fieldset-container')`)

Comment: In repo of mine, example of `Collection` being added in this file: https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form-examples/blob/master/src/Fieldset/CityFieldset.php and it's Factory here: https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form-examples/blob/master/src/Factory/Fieldset/CityFieldsetFactory.php

Comment: I see what you mean, using the DoctineModule ObjectSelect. I'm not sure that can work here though. I'm just looking to set the label of the text input field which is a child of the collection. In the same way, I may want to have the label have a class of the type ID (fixed) of the entity, such that I could style each label for each one differently.

Comment: If, for example, you wanted "short name" instead of "name" as the label for the `CityFieldset#name` property, you could do it for every usage of hte Element inside of the `CityFieldset`. If it's a one-off kind of thing, you could: `$form->get('cities')->getTargetFieldset()->get('name')->setLabel('Short name')`. To set a class replace `setLabel` with `setAttribute('class', 'class-name')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's not quite what I was looking for, as this is to fill in the `ValueOptions` from a repository it seems. These aren't options, rather children of the collection, of which I'd like to have a separate `<label></label>` based on the type.
i.e. `<fieldset><label><span><!-- "Business phone" --></span><input type="text" name="Foo[Bar][0][Phone]" value="123456789"></label></fieldset><fieldset><label><span><!-- "Mobile phone" --></span><input ...` (plus other fields within fieldset)
It doesn't seem possible unfortunately, so some JS will be needed it seem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, so I gave you both these options. First code block the `label` options are to set and configure a `<label>` element for a Fieldset (within a Form). The second code block is the "how to set config" configuration for a Collection of Fieldsets, so that each child-fieldset has a correct label. The last code block sets a label per input (indeed, from a repository). This last comment of yours seems to suggest that you've got different types of Phone, so: different Entities. Each Entity needs it's own fieldset. I've written - cont.

Comment: cont. - I've written te rules about forms that all devs should know about handling forms and using ZF3 [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form#some-information-before-we-dive-in--important-you-understand-).

Comment: Indeed, I agree with your code and rules completely, but I think I've failed to correctly explain (or, possibly, understand). And it is the last code block which was almost relevant, but as far as I understand, `label_generator` is specific to one of `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect`, `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectRadio` or `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox`. I'll update the question with something which could hopefully help explain.

Comment: Ok, finally understand what you specifically wanted ;-) Thought you wanted a label for a fieldset in a collection. But, really what you're after: label based upon type of Entity. The situation you got there is that you need to discriminate between different types of Phone (E.g. mobile phone, land line, satelite, voip phone - right?). So you'll need an `abstract Phone` Entity which requires the basics (country code, net number, full on number) and then a few Discriminator Entities being the types you need: PhoneMobile, PhoneSatellite. You'd have to include these as their own Entities, - cont.

Comment: cont. - and with their own Fieldset (possibly Collection's?) into the base form. Make it possible to add a "required" flag on the Fieldset (see my repo linked earlier) and allow these types to be filled out (or not) and validated (when filled out). The gnarly bit is: you'll have to create an Entity **per type** you require.

Comment: A way around this is to have a Phone Entity (singular) which has: country net number, phone number, extension, whatever, but also: type. "Type" would be filled out by a constant (you choose whether `int` keys or `enum`) and you provide that in a (required) dropdown.

Comment: As an aside: here's some creative ways to have users enter their phone numbers: https://imgur.com/gallery/r102w -> enjoy

Comment: Thanks again. I was hoping there was an other way than discriminator entities or a dropdown :( The joys of following designs! In the end, as the types are fixed I've set them into a JS var, added a label class which I loop, get the sibling type ID field and take the val to map against the types var. Works fine and given there'll typically not be many in the collection, should remain low overhead. And thanks for the link, that's pretty cool!